# Magento 2 - Track order button not work

Tags: magento2, php, admin, orders, magento2.2.2

I have Magento 2.2 and the Track Order button is not working, when I open any order and I press Track Order button I have this error:

```
Shipment #000000013

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Phrase::getTracking() in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/frontend/templates/tracking/details.phtml:22 
Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include() #1 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template), '/home/public_ht...', Array) #2 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/public_ht...') #3 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() #4 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() #5 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/frame in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/frontend/templates/tracking/details.phtml on line 22
```

In that file details.phtml at the line 22 I have this code:

```
$number = is_object($track) ? $track->getTracking() : $track['number'];
```

How I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ussually, this error happens because of carrier `getTracking()` function is not returning the proper value.

You can fix this by modifying the shipping plugin's code located in `app/code/<Plugin name>/<Carrier name>/Model/<carrier name>.php`

Just remove the `getTracking()` function, instead use function `getTrackingInfo()`. Here is the defintion of the function, Just copy paste with necessary modifications.

```
public function getTrackingInfo($trackingNumber)
{
        $tracking = $this->_trackStatusFactory->create();

        $url = 'http://www.stamps.com/shipstatus/?confirmation=' . $trackingNumber; // this is the tracking URL of stamps.com, replace this with your's

        $tracking->setData([
            'carrier' => $this->_code,
            'carrier_title' => $this->getConfigData('title'),
            'tracking' => $trackingNumber,
            'url' => $url,
        ]);
        return $tracking;
}
```

Comment: How does this work ? Should I then call `getTrackingInfo()` in the template ? And what is the `$trackingNumber` given as a parameter if the goal of the function is to return that number ?

Comment: how is this implemented when you are extending `AbstractCarrier` ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by Nishad Up works only for Carriers extending `AbstractCarrierOnline`, for the `AbstractCarrier` you must add initialization of `_trackStatusFactory` into the constructor:

```
protected $_trackStatusFactory;

public function __construct(
    // ..
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory
) {
    // ..

    $this->_trackStatusFactory = $trackStatusFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my **Carrier** created following the Magento instructions ([Add custom shipping carrier](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html)) on a 2.4.2 istance.

I solved in this way, merging @Nishad Up and @Iaroslav Glodov solutions:

It need to add *getTrackingInfo()* method into **app/code/<Vendor_Name>/<Module_Name>/Model/Carrier/<Carrier_Name>.php** class and it doesn't need to remove any functions (*getTracking()* ???).

It is very important to initialize **_trackFactory** and **_trackStatusFactory**

```
/**
 * @var Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory
 */
protected Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $_trackFactory;

/**
 * @var Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory
 */
protected Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $_trackStatusFactory;

public function __construct(
    ..
    Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $trackFactory,
    Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory,
    ..
) {
    ..
    $this->_trackFactory = $trackFactory;
    $this->_trackStatusFactory = $trackStatusFactory;
    ..
}

/**
 * @param $tracking_number
 *
 * @return Status
 */
public function getTrackingInfo($tracking_number)
{
    $result = $this->_trackFactory->create();
    $tracking = $this->_trackStatusFactory->create();

    $tracking->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $tracking->setCarrierTitle('Carrier Title');
    $tracking->setTracking($tracking_number);
    $tracking->setUrl('https://carrier_domain.tld/trackId=' . $tracking_number);
    }

    $result->append($tracking);

    return $tracking;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the fix is easy (vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/frontend/templates/tracking/details.phtml):

```
<table class="data table order tracking" id="tracking-table-popup-<?php /* @noEscape */ echo is_object($track) ? $track->getTracking() : null; ?>">
```

instead of

```
<table class="data table order tracking" id="tracking-table-popup-<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $track->getTracking(); ?>">
```

Comment: there I have this code: <table class="data table order tracking" id="tracking-table-popup-<?= /* @noEscape */ $number ?>">

Comment: your code is not help me anymore